# How many times an element shows in a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I need to know how many times a "phase" shows up, and if it's completed or not.

The final objective is to show:

```
Phase 1: 50% completed
Phase 2: 0% completed
```

**Tasks:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [phase] => 1
            [tasks_status] => completed
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [phase] => 1
            [tasks_status] => pending
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [phase] => 2
            [tasks_status] => pending
        )
)
```

**Phases:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Briefing e Planejamento
            [id] => 1
            [created] => 1437436800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Rabiscos e Design
            [id] => 2
            [created] => 1438128000
        )

)
```

## edit

So, with the help of you guys who answered, I've managed to do it! Here's the result:

```
            /** Define wich tasks has been completed **/
            foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                if ($task['status'] == "completed") {
                    foreach ($fases as &$fase) {
                        if ($fase['id'] == $task['fase_id']) {
                            $fase['numero_total_fases']++;
                            $fase['completed']++;
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($task['status'] == "pending") {
                    foreach ($fases as &$fase) {
                        if ($fase['id'] == $task['fase_id']) {
                            $fase['numero_total_fases']++;
                            $fase['pending']++;
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($task['status'] == "behind schedule") {
                    foreach ($fases as &$fase) {
                        if ($fase['id'] == $task['fase_id']) {
                            $fase['numero_total_fases']++;
                            $fase['behind schedule']++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                unset($fase);
            }

            /** Define progress percentage **/
            foreach ($fases as &$fase) {
                $fase['progresso'] = round(($fase['completed'] / ($fase['numero_total_fases'])) * 100);
            }

            /** Print phases progress **/
            $f = 1;
            foreach ($fases as $fase) {
                echo 'Fase '.$f.' - '.$fase['title'].' = '.$fase['progresso'].'% completed';
            }
```

Comment: *over an hour* So have you wrote some code and tried something or did you just stared at the code for an hour ?

Comment: A bit of both, I tried dozens of things and every 15 minutes or so I would stop and think on how I'm gonna do that... Just couldn't find it

Comment: Then show us 1 of your attempts and we will help you to get it to work.

Comment: Here's some tries... Couldn't go furter back in time because of cntrl+z limitations http://i.imgur.com/2g8Vxza.png

Comment: I know those aren't great examples, it's mostly debugging, but I was seeing no way of accomplishing what I needed

Comment: and what is the logic behind calculating percentages ? when it will be 100% ?

Comment: In the above example, if array[0][task_status] and array[1][task_status] value was "complete", then phase 1 would be 100% completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little slow to the draw, but since I already wrote it, here's my answer too. It's always helpful to see that most programming tasks can be done several ways:

```
<?php 
  $tasks = array(
    array(
      'phase' => 1,
      'tasks_status' => 'completed'
    ),
    array(
      'phase' => 1,
      'tasks_status' => 'pending'
    ),
    array(
      'phase' => 2,
      'tasks_status' => 'pending'
    )
  );
  //$phases = array();
  $phases = array(
    1=>array(
      'title'=>'Briefing e Planejamento',
      'id'=>1,
      'created'=>1437436800
    ),
    2=>array(
      'title'=>'Rabiscos e Design',
      'id'=>2,
      'created'=>1438128000
    )
  );

  foreach($tasks as $key=>$task){
    if(isset($phases[$task['phase']])){
      $thisPhase = $phases[$task['phase']];
    }
    else{
      $thisPhase = array(
        'completed' => 0,
        'pending' => 0
      );
    }
    $thisPhase[$task['tasks_status']]++;
    $phases[$task['phase']] = $thisPhase;
  }

  foreach($phases as $name=>$phase){
    echo $phase['title'].": ".round(($phase['completed'] / ($phase['completed'] + $phase['pending'])) * 100)."% completed <br>";
  }
?>
```

I know you've already finished, but regarding the phases array - you should have put that in the original question if you wanted it worked into the answer. My suggestion, however, would be to use the ID of the phase as the index name in your phases array. The solution I posted will work with that too - and you can then use $phase in the final foreach loop to show the title or created time.

Comment: Hey Mark, please read the comment I left at Jim's answer, it's for you too!

Comment: mark, I've updated my question with the actual $phases array, just in case you want to update your answer... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm still trying to adapt it with no luck, it's harder than I thought... Do you mind taking a look at the $phases array I've added at the question?

Comment: Thanks, I did it! I have edited my question with the final code. Thank you!

Comment: I will set your answer as accepted, because from all 3 yours was the one that I got closer to get the desired result

Comment: Thanks for the accept - and glad to hear you got yourself up and running. I have updated my answer, however, to incorporate your phases array. It's mostly the same, but I used the phase IDs as the keys for the phases array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

I assume you want to calculate the percentage based on your original array.

```
<?php

$tasks = array(
    array(
        'phase' => 1,
        'tasks_status' => 'completed'
    ),
    array(
        'phase' => 1,
        'tasks_status' => 'pending'
    ),
    array(
        'phase' => 2,
        'tasks_status' => 'pending'
    ),
);

$phases_arr = array();
foreach($tasks as $task) {
    if(!array_key_exists($task['phase'], $phases_arr)) {
        $phases_arr[$task['phase']] = array();
    }
    $phases_arr[$task['phase']][] = $task;
}

$phases = array();

foreach($phases_arr as $phase_num => $phase) {
    $p = array(
        'phase' => $phase_num,
        'total' => count($phase),
        'complete' => 0,
        'percent' => 0
    );

    foreach($phase as $task) {
        if($task['complete']) $p['complete']++;
    }

    $p['percent'] = ($p['complete'] / $p['total']) * 100;
    $phases[$phase_num] = $p;
}

foreach($phases as $phase) {
    echo "<p>Phase {$phase['phase']}: {$phase['percent']}% completed</p>";
}
```

Comment: Seriously guys, I'm really thankful. I'm adjusting here for the live version and I'll vote the best answer soon, but either way, you guys are the best. I was simply stuck at this, I'll study your code and try to improve my skills, thanks!

Comment: It's very rough and could definitely be improved! But you are very welcome :)!

Comment: I'm still trying to implement it, because my $phases array is a bit different, I've updated the question to show it, just in case you wish to update your answer

Comment: What is the phases array for? Just to show the name instead of the number?

Comment: Is it too complicated? It's not just about the name, it will be easier to work on the script if it's built like that... I'm ashamed to ask too much, but I have to admit I couldn't do it! I slept, just wake up and I'm still trying, but no luck so far, I really don't know what to do. Sorry about this annoyance...

Comment: Thanks, I did it! I have edited my question with the final code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs,

```
$tasks = array( array('phase' => 1, 'tasks_status' => 'completed'),
                array('phase' => 1, 'tasks_status' => 'pending'),
                array('phase' => 2, 'tasks_status' => 'pending'),
          );
```

Consider this,

```
$phase = array();

foreach ($tasks as $key => $value)
{
    $phase[$value['phase']][] = $value['tasks_status'] == 'completed' ? 50 : 0 ;
}

function get_phase_percentage($i)
{
    global $phase;
    if(isset($phase[$i]) && is_array($phase[$i]))
        return array_sum($phase[$i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Use it like,

```
Phase 1: <?php echo get_phase_percentage(1)?>% completed
Phase 2: <?php echo get_phase_percentage(2)?>% completed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Viral, I'm trying to implement it - I've posted my $phases array just in case you wish to update your answer - thanks a lot again

Comment: Viral, I coudln't make it work on my $phases array, I've updated the question, do you mind taking a look?

Comment: Thanks, I did it! I have edited my question with the final code. Thank you!